# SQL: use dynamic default value in ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL DB with 3 tables `object`, `user` and `company` with following relationships:

- an object is created by a user
- a user belongs to a company.

Now I'd like to add following relationship:

- an object is owned by a company

To that purpose I want to add a new mandatory foreign key `company_id` into the table `object`. To fill the existing rows I need to define a default value. The default `company_id` should be given by the foreign key `company_id` from table `user`.

Is it possible to define the default value dynamicaly like this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE object
        ADD company_id BIGINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES company(id) DEFAULT (SELECT user.company_id from user where user.id = object.user_id);
COMMIT;
```

Or should I better use sql variable?
What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post.

Comment: Do you plan do drop `object.user_id` afterwards? Otherwise the new column isn't necessary, the company can be determined via the user. The new column is even harmful then, as it can lead to inconsistencies -- what if the user of an object isn't in the company of an object?

Comment: No, an object can be created by a user of company A but owned by company B, so it's all fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can do this in most DBMS I can think of...
Probably just add the column as nullable, run an UPDATE statement, then alter the column to be non-nullable